# Drop all rows from data frame that follow a filter threshold using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This feels like a common enough task that I assume there's an established function/method for accomplishing it.  I'm imagining a function like `dplyr::filter_after()` but there doesn't seem to be one.

Here's the method I'm using as a starting point:

```
#Setup:
library(dplyr)
threshold <- 3
test.df <- data.frame("num"=c(1:5,1:5),"let"=letters[1:10])

#Drop every row that follows the first 3, including that row:
out.df <- test.df %>%
  mutate(pastThreshold = cumsum(num>=threshold)) %>%
  filter(pastThreshold==0) %>%
  dplyr::select(-pastThreshold)
```

This produces the desired output:

```
> out.df
  num let
1   1   a
2   2   b
```

Is there another solution that's less verbose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` provides the window functions `cumany` and `cumall`, that filter all rows after/before a condition becomes false for the first time. [Documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/cumall.html).

```
test.df %>% 
  filter(cumall(num<threshold)) #all rows until condition violated for first time
#   num let
# 1   1   a
# 2   2   b
```

Comment: Cool Cool. This is what I had in my mind.  I was sure there was a dplyr function to do this directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
test.df %>%
 slice(1:which.max(num == threshold)-1)

  num let
1   1   a
2   2   b
```

Comment: I find this more intuitive and more explainable than the cumsum approach with a slight modification: slice(1:first(which(num == threshold))-1)

Answer (score 1):

We can use the same in `filter` without the need for creating extra column and later removing it

```
library(dplyr)
test.df %>% 
     filter(cumsum(num>=threshold) == 0)
#   num let
#1   1   a
#2   2   b
```

---

Or another option is `match` with `slice`

```
test.df  %>%
    slice(seq_len(match(threshold-1, num)))
```

Or another option is `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
test.df %>%
     filter(rleid(num >= threshold) == 1)
```

Comment: Obviously...  Thanks. I guess I was overthinking it.